# Updating nginx cache in the background

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx server that is acting as a proxy to a 3rd party API, requests to the API can be  a bit slow sometimes and pages that rely on the slower API calls can take a long time to load when the items in the cache have expired.

Is there anyway to have something similar to the following happen:

- Request comes into the proxy, there is nothing in the cache so it sends the request to the API and caches it.
- Subsequent requests result in the proxy immediately return a cached result
- The cache expires
- The next request results in the proxy serving the stale cached result, but then somehow nginx fetches the fresh content from the API and updates its cache.
- When the cache has updated users start seeing the updated content.

The crucial thing is when nginx retrieves the fresh content it does so after serving the stale content and so the user making the request doesn't have to wait for it to complete.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I think the closest possible behaviour will be the next:</s>

1. If a cache item is stalled then the first request will wait for
   response from upstream (API) server.
2. In the meantime, other requests for the same cache item will receive the stalled result.

This behaviour can be enabled by `proxy_cache_use_stale updating`.

Please see [proxy_cache_use_stale](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_use_stale) documentation for more. 
You also may be interested in [proxy_cache_lock](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_lock)

Source: [NGINX caching webinar and notes](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-high-performance-caching/)

Actually, the behaviour that is mentioned in the question is supported by NGINX. Sorry for the incorrect answer. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40134179/1079966