# Stale-while-revalidate cache replacement from Varnish

Tags: nginx, varnish, plesk, http-caching

We are currently moving our servers to a new one, with PLESK 12.5 which doesn't support Varnish cache for our PHP applications.

We use Varnish, mostly for the 'stale-while-revalidate' capability, so that we can send whole pages or parts (using ESI) without any waiting time for any customer while cache is refreshing.

Is there any alternative to Varnish for a similar kind of cache ? Either another "program" that could run on PLESK, or any PHP/server cache ?

PLESK comes with NGINX, but it does not seem to provide 'stale-while-revalidate' capabilities ; I also know Squid isn't supported on PLESK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually nginx provides stale-while-revalidate by [proxy_cache_use_stale](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_use_stale) and [Nginx supports Cache-Control extensions since 1.11.10](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_background_update):

```
location / {
    ...
    proxy_cache_use_stale updating error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    proxy_cache_background_update on;
}
```

<strike>Yes, it does not support Cache-Control extension,  with  so if your application does not use stale-while-revalidate in Cache-Control header nginx will be enough.</strike>

Comment: Thanks for your anwsers, I'm still trying to install NGINX correctly with this "proxy_cache_use_stale"  property. However it won't exactly work as I want, as the 1st user requesting an unfresh resource will have to wait, but I may find a workaround

Comment: It's looks exactly like behaviour of 'updating' parameter as described here https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/. Maybe to remove it?

Comment: Finally managed to correctly install NGINX with "proxy_cache_stale". Works fine for everyone but the first user requesting a non-cached entry, so I made a script to call the longest page with a cache_bypass directive. Thx for your help

Comment: @elwood is your script available anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to setup Varnish port in Plesk nginx config template:

```
# it's for Plesk 17
cat /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/domain/service/proxy.php
<?php
/**
 * @var Template_VariableAccessor $VAR
 * @var array $OPT
 */
?>
<?php if ($OPT['ssl']): ?>
        proxy_pass https://<?php echo $OPT['ipAddress']->proxyEscapedAddress . ':' . '6081' ?>;
<?php else: ?>
        proxy_pass http://<?php echo $OPT['ipAddress']->proxyEscapedAddress . ':' . '6081' ?>;
<?php endif ?>
        proxy_set_header Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
<?php if (!$VAR->domain->physicalHosting->proxySettings['nginxTransparentMode'] && !$VAR->domain->physicalHosting->proxySettings['nginxServeStatic']): ?>
        proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
<?php endif ?>
        access_log off;
```

So for domains in proxy mode requests will be proxied to Varnish and than to Apache on port 7080.